# Horizontal Scroll in IOS doesn't work ReactJs

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to scroll from left to right onClick button img and doesnt do anything on IOS.

I tried using scrollTo but doesn't work.

```
function scrollRight() {
    var scrollAmount = 0;
    var slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
      artSection.scrollLeft += 20;
      scrollAmount += 20;
      if (scrollAmount >= artSection.clientWidth) {
        window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
      }
    }, 25);
    window.scrollTo(10000, 10000);
  }

<img
            className="left"
            src={left}
            style={opacityLeft}
            alt="Left arrow"
            onClick={scrollLeft}
          />
```

The scrollLeft just work in Android and Desktop.

http://iequiz.yondbee.com/quiz/

Comment: Can you also provide some HTML and CSS? We really need a [mcve] to be able to help.

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is enough the html, css? http://iequiz.yondbee.com/quiz/

Comment: This might be annoying, but can you include a [mcve] in the question itself using a stack snippet if possible. Even though you’ve done what I asked links aren’t as helpful as they tend to “rot”.